# Set a variation out of stock in all WooCommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, variable-product

We have mugs printing system with WooCommerce and we display available printable colors as variations. I need to set out of stock a certain variation in all products, i.e., if we do not have red color availability then I want to set red variation out of stock in all the products.

I didn't find any simple solution for this except setting out of stock the certain variation in all products manually.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear: How do you know in WooCommerce that for example the red color is not available anymore? How do you trigger that information?

Comment: By red color, I mean that Red ink is not available for printing. As I mentioned that we are running a printing store. So, when we run out of red ink, we want to set `red-variation` to out of stock in all products.
I want to manually add a code in functions.php that can do the job.

Comment: Not more clear: So how do wooCommerce know that Red is not available for printing?

Comment: Sorry for not being able to describe clearly. I want to manually put a code in `functions.php` that can set `out of stock` a particular variation for all products. Once, it will be in stock, I will manually remove that code.

Comment: Yes it should be, But how do you trigger that event?… How do WooCommerce know that it need to change stock status of all that variations in different variable product? This seems a real development and you should hire a developer for that.

Comment: I am looking if there's any WooCommerce hook that can change stock status of all variable products.

Comment: You may try to use [`woocommerce_available_variation` filter hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_available_variation)

Answer (score -1):

$out_of_stock_staus = 'outofstock';

// Updating the stock quantity
update_post_meta($product_id, '_stock', 0);
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_stock_status', wc_clean( $out_of_stock_staus ) );
wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, 'outofstock', 'product_visibility', true );

I think this meta value you suppose to manage for handling the stock for woocommerce product
I don't know regarding hook but this function may help you to figure out